# Prove that $(a, b)$ is prime in $\mathbb{H}$ if $||(a, b)||$ is prime in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Numbers in $H$ are ordered pairs of integers, i.e. $(a,b) \in \mathbb{H}$ if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Z}$

Multiplication is defined as

$(a, b)$ x $(c, d) := (ac-5bd , ad+bc)$

For any number $(a,b) \in \mathbb{H}$, we define its norm $||(a,b)||$ by

$||(a, b)|| := a^2+5(b^2)$

Prove that $(a, b)$ is prime in $\mathbb{H}$ if $||(a, b)||$ is prime in $\mathbb{N}$

How could I go about this question?

Also if I wanted to show number say (5,0) is not prime in $\mathbb{H}$ even though 5 is prime in $\mathbb{N}$ would I go about it the same way?

Comment: The key fact is that the norm of a product is the product of the norms. The post does not specify the product operation on $H$. One can guess what it is intended to be, but it really should be specified.

Comment: Note that $H=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Answer (score 1):

The key facts here are that $|ab| = |a||b|$ and the norm of an integer in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is an integer in $\mathbb{N}$.

So if $q$ is such that $|q| = p$ is prime in $\mathbb{N}$, then for any way of writing $q$ as a product $q = ab$, we have that $|ab|=|a||b| = p$. Of course, the only (positive) factors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$, so one of $a,b$ is actually a unit. Thus $q$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

You also ask about showing that $5$ is not a prime. While it is true that $|5| = 25$, it is not the case that the norm of every prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is actually a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. However, this is brute-forcable, just like prime verification in the normal integers. Naively, you only have to look at numbers whose norm is less than $25$. And there are not so many of these.

Or you might just see that $5 = -\sqrt{-5} \cdot \sqrt{-5} = (0,-1)\cdot(0,1)$, where the latter is in your notation but the left is in the common notation.